# Getting _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Response>'

Tags: dart, flutter

I´m new in Dart/Flutter and I'm trying to get the result of a future that consumes a webservice:

```
 Future<Map> _readData() async {
   (...)


http.Response response = await http.post(
    request,
    headers: {
      "SOAPAction": "http://www.totvs.com/IwsConsultaSQL/RealizarConsultaSQL",
      "Content-Type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
      "Authorization": "Basic bWVzdHJlOnRvdHZz",
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
    },
    body: utf8.encode(requestBody),
    encoding: Encoding.getByName("UTF-8")
).then((onValue){

  (...)


  var dataFinal = jsonDecode(jsondataFinal);

  return  dataFinal ;
});
```

And in my init state I call this function, so I can use this result to build my layout:

```
     @override
  void initState () {
    super.initState();
    _readData().then((data){
      setState(() {
        print(data);

      });

    });

  }
```

I always get this exception:

```
_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Response>'
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to use `await` and `then` together.

Comment: Ok, but this is not the question :D, I'll adjust this, but even without await it give me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use await and then in the same time. Your code should be like below

```
Future<Map> _readData() async {
(...)

http.Response response = await http.post(
    request,
    headers: {
      "SOAPAction": "http://www.totvs.com/IwsConsultaSQL/RealizarConsultaSQL",
      "Content-Type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
      "Authorization": "Basic bWVzdHJlOnRvdHZz",
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
    },
    body: utf8.encode(requestBody),
    encoding: Encoding.getByName("UTF-8")
);

  var dataFinal = jsonDecode(response.body);

  return  dataFinal ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this error appear with this code?

```
Future<Map> _readData() async {
  //...
  http.Response response = await http.post(
    request,
    headers: {
      "SOAPAction": "http://www.totvs.com/IwsConsultaSQL/RealizarConsultaSQL",
      "Content-Type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
      "Authorization": "Basic bWVzdHJlOnRvdHZz",
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
    },
    body: utf8.encode(requestBody),
    encoding: Encoding.getByName("UTF-8")
  );
  //...
  var dataFinal = jsonDecode(jsondataFinal);
  return  dataFinal ;
}
```